# how to redirect output from sed command to a file

Tags: sed

I have a log that produce lots of text in the line along side the string that i want to get. basically it contains something like:

```
bla bla bla packet 12 out of 432 bla bla
```

I have this big command:

```
tail -f log.txt |grep --line-buffered "packet" |sed -n 's/.*\(packet [0-9]* out of [0-9]*\).*/\1/p' |while read log; do echo "$(date +%F_%H:%m:%S:%N) $log" ; done
```

and I want to redirect the output to file.

Why `>> file` does not work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My first approach in order to solve this issue will be, is command working or giving any output on terminal? If yes then go for why it is not putting any output into an output file etc. Try it once and let us know then.

Comment: At which step do you want to redirect output to file?

Comment: i change it. i need to find the lines that contain 'packet', then filter out in that lines only the pattern in sed, then using while loop print the output + timestamp to file or to screen. when i use sed it doesn't print to screen or to file. it only works without sed. but if i run only the sed command on the file without the while loop it works only to screen and not to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is that the sed command holds the output data in a buffer. You are avoided the data synchronization issue for the grep command (2nd in the pipe chain) by using --line-buffered parameter, using -u parameter for next piped sed command help to fix this issue. The command should be:

```
tail -f log.txt | grep --line-buffered "packet" | sed -n -u 's/.*\(packet [0-9]* out of [0-9]*\).*/\1/p' | while read log; do echo "$(date +%F_%H:%m:%S:%N) $log" >> outputfile.log ; done
```

sed -n **-u** 's/.*(packet [0-9]* out of [0-9]*).*/\1/p'

Instead of

sed -n 's/.*(packet [0-9]* out of [0-9]*).*/\1/p'

With this change the redirect to file should work.

Comment: Your welcome sir. Could you please accept this answer ?. Thanks in advance.